# I have to build my Project 2 times, the first time it fails, because it can't open a library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, cmake, websocket++

My problem happens to be, that every time I regenerate my Project with CMake and try to build it afterwards with VisualStudio, it takes 2 tries, the first time it always fails, because of a library that can't be opened, but which is already there. The second time I build it, it works flawlessly.

I guess it's because of I let VisualStudio automatically pull and include that library and Something in my CMake file is in the wrong order, but I don't really know.

This is the CMake code that includes Asio and Websocket++ into the Project, the file VS can't open is the Asio.lib file in the last line.
Websocket++ needs Asio to run.

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DASIO_STANDALONE )
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_WEBSOCKETPP_CPP11_RANDOM_DEVICE_)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_WEBSOCKETPP_CPP11_TYPE_TRAITS_)

Include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(extasio
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/tobiasrau/asio.git
    GIT_TAG cmake)
ExternalProject_Add(extwebsocketpp
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/TobiasPiontek/websocketpp.git)

include_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/include "build/extwebsocketpp-prefix/src/extwebsocketpp/install/include" "build/extasio-prefix/src/extasio/include")
target_link_libraries(Test ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/extasio-prefix/src/extasio/lib/asio.lib)
```

thank you in advance, for the help

Answer (score 0):

For being sure that `ExternalProject` is built before your executable, you need to add corresponded dependency:

```
add_dependencies(Test extasio)
```

Similarly, for make sure one `ExternalProject` is build before another, specify dependency between them:

```
add_dependencies(extwebsocketpp extasio)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot, but there is still a small problem, it works every time now, except when I build it the first time and there is not even a build folder, it fails. Rebuilding works now.

Comment: Could you show the error which you get when build the project the first time? You may add it to your question post (with appropriate description).